# getting Time and Date differences PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to get the differences of dates. I am a newbie, please understand. Here are some parts:

(Original Lines)

```
$BirthDate = "$month $day $year";
$dateBirth = date('F j, Y',strtotime($BirthDate));
```

These lines are actually working, however, I want to add more info like the hours, minutes, seconds and ante meridiem. I modified the code and here's what I did:

(Modified Lines)

```
$BirthDate = "$month $day $year $hours $minutes $seconds $ampm";
$dateBirth = date('F j, Y h:i:s a',strtotime($BirthDate));
```

Yes, the original lines work, the echo the correct inputted data.
Problem is, when I did the Modified Lines, the output becomes:

```
January 1, 1970 08:00:00 am
```

I can't somehow think of any solution to this. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Please mark you code use code tag.

Comment: We need to know what does the value in $BirthDate looks like.

Comment: is the question about time differences or about that weird date/time output? i don't see a qustion regarding how to get the differences.

Comment: `$BirthDate = sprintf("%s-%s-%s %s:%s:%s %s", $year, $month, $day, $hours, $minutes, $seconds, $ampm);`

Comment: @tradyblix, I cant proceed to getting differences because Im stuck at getting wrong outputs.

Comment: well, re-phrase your question because it doesn't relate to what you're asking regarding `January 1, 1970 08:00:00 am`. when you get to time differences ask about it if you encounter a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `\DateTime` object and it's difference method `DateTime::dff`. Procedural style would be `date_diff`.

[Manual entry](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Example:

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could help

```
$birth_date = "2006-01-16"; 
$todays_date = date("Y-m-d"); 
$today = strtotime($todays_date); 
$b_date = strtotime($birth_date); 

if ($b_date > $today) { 
    $valid = "yes"; 
} else { 
    $valid = "no"; 
}
```